# GKSession is deprecated in ios 7, what should I use now?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, deprecated, gksession

I have a few apps that use game kit to transfer files between devices but in ios 7 gamekit does not work correctly.  I am wondering what I should use now.

Answer (score 13):

You will now want to use the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328) in iOS 7 for:

> discovering services provided by nearby iOS devices using
>   infrastructure Wi-Fi networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth
>   personal area networks and subsequently communicating with those
>   services by sending message-based data, streaming data, and resources
>   (such as files)

Comment: Have you found any good posts that explain how to use this framework with example code?  GKpeerpicker was pretty easy and had its own view controller.  MC does not appear to be as easy to use. I would like to do file transfers with it the way i used to in GK.

Comment: The WWDC 2013 Session video is a good start. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Comment: Youh have on exemple here [MultipeerGroupChat](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Is there a way I can do a communication between iOS6 and iOS7 device? GameKit won't work on OS7 and Multipeer Connectivity won't work on OS6.

Comment: @Anshul did you find any solution to make connection between iOS6 and iOS7?

Comment: @Siddiq: No.. nothing so far. It seems like the only way left is to create a Bonjour service and transfer data over wi-fi. No way to establish P-2-P Bluetooth connection.